# Get values form multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Right now, this block of code displays VLANs. I'm trying to display only the names(TLSoIP_JB1, TLSoIP_JB2, TLSoIP_JB3)

```
Array ( 

         [0] => Array ( [0] => TLSoIP_JB1 [1] => 1 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [0] => TLSoIP_JB2 [1] => 2 ) 
         [2] => Array ( [0] => TLSoIP_JB3 [1] => 3 ) 
     )
```

Regards Philipp

Comment: Have you tried _anything_? Do you even know how to work with arrays? Multi-dimensional arrays aren't too different form simple arrays, except for `$array['key']` becomes `$array['keyofSubArr']['key']`. In this particular example `$arr[0][0]; $arr[1][0]; $arr[2][0]` will give you `TLSoIP_JB1 `, `TLSoIP_JB2 ` and `TLSoIP_JB3 ` respectively

Comment: Yes and no. My result was every time `array`. I've forgotten `[0]` after the `$inner_array`. I'm sorry for my incompetence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $inner_array) {
    echo $inner_array[0];
}
```

Or you can store the desired values in a separate array and print it afterwards:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $inner_array) {
    $new_array[] = $inner_array[0];
}
print_r($new_array);
```